# android passing 2000 size array from one activity to another

Tags: android, arrays, android-activity

i need to pass 3 arry that size approx ***2000*** to ***3000***+ string each... is it possible? as i am getting large transaction error

i need to do this

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            Test_My_Paging_Activity.class);
                    i.putExtra("string-array", android_img_array);
                    i.putExtra("string-array_ID", array_ID);
                    i.putExtra("string-array_thumb", array);

                    // getActivity().finish();


                    startActivity(i);

Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
       array = b.getStringArray("string-array");
                array_ID = b.getStringArray("string-array_ID");
                array_thumb = b.getStringArray("string-array_thumb");
```

Comment: you could try to store these values in your extended Application http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: Why aren't you using a database, instead?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is the usage of these arrays, but, you may implement Singleton storage class , and read the 3-arrays from it in the Second activity.

Answer (score 0):

for a solution, you can create a class and define array as static in that class.and pass an identifier from one activity to another so you can determine which array is needed.

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned, you can store the data in another class or even in a database. To store it in another class, do something like this:

```java
public class ActivityOne extends Activity {
    //code...
    StorageClass.android_img_array = ...
    StorageClass.array_ID = ...
    StorageClass.array = ...
    //code...
}

public class ActivityOne extends Activity {
    //code...
    String[] myArray = StorageClass.android_img_array;
}

public class StorageClass {
    public static String[] android_img_array;
    public static String[] array_ID;
    public static String[] array;
    //your code here...
}
```